# Inicializar array dentro de un método en java

Tags: java, array, metodos

Hola tengo un array declarado en main que lo paso a un método pero no me deja inicializarlo en este, me da error o de la siguiente manera se ejecuta pero el array se queda como null
Hay alguna forma de declarar el array en main y hacer el new en el método?
De antemano muchas gracias :)

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] hola=null;
    aaa(hola);
    if (hola != null) System.out.print("1");
    else System.out.print(hola[0]);
}
static void aaa(String [] hola){
    hola= new String [2];
    hola[0]="pe";
    return;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada voy a dejar la solución a tu código.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] hola = null;
        hola = aaa(hola);
                
        if (hola != null) {
            System.out.print("1");
        } else {
            System.out.print(hola[0]);
        }
    }

    static String[] aaa(String[] hola) {
        hola = new String[2];
        hola[0] = "pe";
        
        return hola;
    }
}
```

Fíjate que tu método `aaa()` ahora devuelve un array, ya no devuelve void y por lo tanto podemos "capturar" en el array `hola` lo que devuelve, básicamente un array.

Ahora unas correcciones, en la parte del `if` no tiene sentido lo que haces, te comento.

```java
    if (hola != null) {
        System.out.print("1");
    } else {
        System.out.print(hola[0]);
    }
```

Si tu array `hola` es distinto de `null`tu pintas un "1" por consola, pero si no es distinto intentas obtener la primera posición de un `null`, cosa que no se puede y te saldrá un error de tipo `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Tampoco entiendo que necesidad tienes de iniciar tu array en otro método pero pero bueno no me voy a meter ahí, solo he dejado tu código sin errores la parte de buenas practicas ya la aprenderás con el tiempo